# Calling the FB.init() on app relaunch, Phonegap in IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

Im having a issue with phonegap and the Facebook connect plugin.
On first run the FB.init() works fine and logging in works fine too. But once I exit the app and close it from the the background running and then relaunches the app again it fails, and crashes on FB.init();  (ONLY ON RELAUNCH)

Anyone had a similar issue?

FB.init()

```
    FB._initialized = true;
    FB.init({
        appId           : '4231527********',
        nativeInterface : CDV.FB
    });
```

I´ve tried resetting the local storage variables with ...

```
  storage.removeItem("cdv_fb_session");
  storage.removeItem("FB_templateDataResponse");
```

Is there another way?

Is it possible to run any other function, similar to the FB.logout() thats doesn't require to have been initialized with FB.init()?

Is there anyway to disable the autologin on FB.INIT() ?